# Not able to click on element using relative xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button which contains img tag

```
<button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Home.png" height="60px" width="60px" title="My Home">
</button>
```

Its absolute xpath is

```
/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/tooltip/tip-cont/tooltip/a/button
```

when i click it using this relative xpath it clicks the element, but when i use relative xpath,

```
(//button[@class='home-page-img-btn'])[9]
```

it says it clicked but on my browser nothing is clicked. What can I write to not use absolute xpath?

This is the whole html code for reference from inspect elements

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="caleajoMemberApp" class="ng-scope"><head>....</head>
<body>
<div id="loader" ng-show="showLoader" class="ng-hide"></div>
<!--<div class="nav-adjustment"></div>-->
<!-- ngInclude: '../common/html/nav-bar.html' --><nav class="caleajo-nav-top ng-scope" ng-include="'../common/html/nav-bar.html'"><div class="container top-nav-panel ng-scope" ng-controller="HeaderController as ctrl" style="color: whitesmoke">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->


    <div class="navbar-header col-md-4 col-sm-4 zero-padding">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home">
            <img height="40" style="height: 40px;" src="../common/img/New-Caleajo-Logo-04.png" class="caleajo-brand">
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <!--<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>-->
        <div class="pull-right col-lg-8  col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row" style="height: 50px">
               <!-- <div class="pull-right col-md-8  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="input-group" style="padding: 20px">
                       &lt;!&ndash; <input type="text" class="form-control"
                               placeholder="{{ 'cmnStr.Search' | translate}}"> <span
                            class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>&ndash;&gt;
                    </div>

                </div>-->
            </div>
            <!--input-group -->
            <div class="row login-menu-row" style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;margin-bottom: 25px;margin-top: -15px">
                <li style="height: 40px">
                    <!-- ngIf: showNotificationIcon --><ul ng-if="showNotificationIcon" class="ng-scope">
                       <a ng-click="ctrl.gotoUpdate()">
                           <!--<img src="../common/img/My-Messages.png" style="height: 40px;width: 40px">-->
                           <i class="fa fa-bell-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 30px;cursor: pointer;padding: 0px;"></i>
                               <!-- ngIf: notificationCounts.ALL != 0 --><span class="badge badge-notify-nav ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="notificationCounts.ALL != 0">3</span><!-- end ngIf: notificationCounts.ALL != 0 -->
                       </a>
                    </ul><!-- end ngIf: showNotificationIcon -->
                    <ul style="border-left: #000000 solid medium;"><a href="/logout"><span class="ng-binding">Log Out</span></a></ul>
                    <ul style="border-left: #000000 solid medium;"><a href="#help"><span class="ng-binding">Help</span></a></ul>

                </li>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

<!-- /.container-fluid -->



</nav>

<div class="wrapper" style="margin-top: 0px">
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0px">

            <div class="row visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md top-menu-panel">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1">
                        <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Home' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Home"> <a ui-sref="home" href="#/home">
                            <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Home.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Home">
                            </button>

                        </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Home</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1 ">
                        <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Profile' | translate}}" tooltip-side="bottom" class="tooltips _bottom _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Profile"> <a ui-sref="profileDashboard" href="#/profile-dashboard">
                            <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Profile.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Profile">
                            </button>
                        </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Profile</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1">
                        <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Jobs' | translate}}" tooltip-side="bottom" class="tooltips _bottom _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Jobs"> <a ui-sref="memberJobListing" href="#/job">
                            <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Jobs.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Jobs">
                            </button>
                        </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Jobs</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1 ">
                        <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Applications' | translate}}" tooltip-side="left" class="tooltips _left _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Applications"> <a ui-sref="memberJobApplication" href="#/application">
                            <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Applications.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Applications">
                            </button>
                        </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Applications</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1">
                        <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Interviews' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Interviews"> <a ui-sref="myInterview" href="#/my_interview">
                            <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Interviews.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Interviews">
                            </button>
                        </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Interviews</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1">
                        <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'CV' | translate}}" tooltip-side="bottom" class="tooltips _bottom _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My CV"> <a ui-sref="cvList" href="#/cv">
                            <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/CV.png" class="home-page-img" title="My CV">
                            </button>
                        </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My CV</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                    </div>


                    <!-- ngIf: ShowJourney --><div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1 ng-scope" ng-if="ShowJourney">
                        <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Journey' | translate}}" tooltip-side="bottom" class="tooltips _bottom _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Journey"> <a ui-sref="myJourneyWizard.talent" href="#/my_journey/talent">
                            <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Journey.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Journey">
                            </button>
                        </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Journey</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                    </div><!-- end ngIf: ShowJourney -->





                    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1">
                        <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Files' | translate}}" tooltip-side="bottom" class="tooltips _bottom _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Files"> <a ui-sref="uploads" href="#/uploads">
                            <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Files.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Files">
                            </button>
                        </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Files</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row-fluid row-equal" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">

                <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1  hidden-xs hidden-sm left-nav-panel col-equal text-center" align="center" style="z-index: 9999999">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Home' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Home"> <a class="hvr-grow" ui-sref="home" href="#/home">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Home.png" height="60px" width="60px" title="My Home">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Home</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 " style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Profile' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Profile"> <a class="hvr-grow" ui-sref="profileDashboard" href="#/profile-dashboard">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Profile.png" height="60px" width="60px" title="My Profile">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Profile</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Jobs' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Jobs"> <a class="hvr-grow" ui-sref="memberJobListing" href="#/job">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Jobs.png" height="60px" width="60px" title="My Jobs">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Jobs</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Applications' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Applications"> <a class="hvr-grow" ui-sref="memberJobApplication" href="#/application">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Applications.png" height="60px" width="60px" title="My Applications">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Applications</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Interviews' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Interviews"> <a class="hvr-grow" ui-sref="myInterview" href="#/my_interview">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Interviews.png" height="60px" width="60px" title="My Interviews">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Interviews</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'CV' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My CV"> <a class="hvr-grow" ui-sref="cvList" href="#/cv">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/CV.png" height="60px" width="60px" title="My CV">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My CV</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                    <!-- ngIf: ShowJourney --><div class="row ng-scope" ng-if="ShowJourney">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Journey' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Journey"> <a class="hvr-grow" ui-sref="myJourneyWizard.talent" href="#/my_journey/talent">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Journey.png" height="60px" width="60px" title="My Journey">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Journey</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end ngIf: ShowJourney -->

                    <div class="row">


                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Files' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Files"> <a class="hvr-grow" ui-sref="uploads" href="#/uploads">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Files.png" height="60px" width="60px" title="My Files">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Files</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="row hidden-xs visible-sm  hidden-md top-menu-panel">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Home' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Home"> <a ui-sref="home" href="#/home">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Home.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Home">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Home</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Profile' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Profile"> <a ui-sref="profileDashboard" href="#/profile-dashboard">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Profile.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Profile">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Profile</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Jobs' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Jobs"> <a ui-sref="memberJobListing" href="#/job">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Jobs.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Jobs">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Jobs</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Applications' | translate}}" tooltip-side="left" class="tooltips _left _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Applications"> <a ui-sref="memberJobApplication" href="#/application">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Applications.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Applications">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Applications</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Interviews' | translate}}" tooltip-side="left" class="tooltips _left _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Interviews"> <a ui-sref="myInterview" href="#/my_interview">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Interviews.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Interviews">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Interviews</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'CV' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My CV"> <a ui-sref="cvList" href="#/cv">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/CV.png" class="home-page-img" title="My CV">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My CV</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ngIf: ShowJourney --><div class="row ng-scope" ng-if="ShowJourney">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Journey' | translate}}" tooltip-side="right" class="tooltips _right _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Journey"> <a ui-sref="myJourneyWizard.talent" href="#/my_journey/talent">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Journey.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Journey">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Journey</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end ngIf: ShowJourney -->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <!-- tooltips:  --><tooltip tooltip-template="{{'My' | translate}} {{'Files' | translate}}" tooltip-side="bottom" class="tooltips _bottom _steady _ready"><tip-cont><tooltip class="ng-scope" tooltip-template="My Files"> <a ui-sref="uploads" href="#/uploads">
                                <button type="button" class="home-page-img-btn">
                                    <img src="img/home-white-icon-only/Files.png" class="home-page-img" title="My Files">
                                </button>
                            </a> </tooltip></tip-cont><tip class=""><tip-tip><span id="close-button" style="display: none;">×</span>My Files</tip-tip><tip-arrow></tip-arrow></tip></tooltip>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11 col-lg-11 col-sm-12 col-equal ui-view-panel" id="body" style="margin: 0px; min-height: 815px;">

                    <!-- ngIf: (breadcrumb && breadcrumb.length > 0) --><!-- ngInclude: '../common/html/breadcrumb.html' --><div class="row-fluid ng-scope" ng-if="(breadcrumb &amp;&amp; breadcrumb.length > 0)" ng-include="'../common/html/breadcrumb.html'"><!-- ngIf: breadcrumb --><h4 ng-if="breadcrumb" style="font-size: 16px;padding-left: 10px;padding-bottom: 0px;" class="ng-scope">
        <!-- ngRepeat: link in breadcrumb --><span ng-repeat="link in breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb-link ng-scope">
            <!-- ngIf: link.name --><a href="#/home" class="breadcrumb-link ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="link.name "> Home</a><!-- end ngIf: link.name -->&nbsp; <!-- ngIf: link.name --><i class="fa fa-circle  ng-scope" style="font-size: 8px;vertical-align: middle" aria-hidden="true" ng-if="link.name "></i><!-- end ngIf: link.name --> &nbsp;
        </span><!-- end ngRepeat: link in breadcrumb -->
</h4><!-- end ngIf: breadcrumb -->
<!-- ngIf: pageHeader  && !hideTitle --></div><!-- end ngIf: (breadcrumb && breadcrumb.length > 0) -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ng-toast ng-toast--center ng-toast--top ng-toast--animate-slide"><ul class="ng-toast__list"><!-- ngRepeat: message in messages --></ul></div>
```

PS. I removed the  contents and script as text was over character limit

Answer (score 0):

I think you may seriously simplify your expression:

```
//button[@class = 'home-page-img-btn']
```

Or, additionally checking the `img` element's title (looks like this would guarantee uniqueness):

```
//button[@class = 'home-page-img-btn' and img/@title = 'My Home']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this relative `XPath`:

```
//button[@class="home-page-img-btn"][img[@src="img/home-white-icon-only/Home.png"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to use absolute XPath because, It takes more time to find an element from starting node So better way to use relative path to locate the element.

Also there is one better way to make your customized xpath other then copy & paste from `Firepath`

like this way -

`//button/img[@title='My Home']`

or

`//button/img[@src='img/home-white-icon-only/Home.png']`

Comment: The edit you did in the question is `This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.` pls avoid in future.

Comment: @manish, I think what i have written is right context  `when i click it using this relative xpath it clicks the element, but when i use relative xpath,` what is meaning of this . can you please suggest me ?

Comment: Don't edit questions if you don't know what are you going to do. [Don't **HUNT** for reps.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

Answer (score 0):

While Creating Xpath you have to very sure of below points

- No to Absolute XPath: If the xpath is heavily dependent on the Page structure , it is bound to come at a maintenance cost  - Not good practice.
- Make Sure the Relative Xpath are unique as well, People do tend to define generalized Xpaths and then falter to create unique locators.

For your solution , Try the below Xpath:

```
//button//img[@title='My Home']
```